# how to render template value depending on model param value passed?

Tags: templates, grails, model, render, gsp

I want to render same template on one page which should display the value depending on the param value(3 or 4).
View is --

```
 <td >
<g:render template="gdxqStatusTemplate" model="[param:3]" /> </td>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td >
<g:render template="gdxqStatusTemplate" model="[param:4]" /> </td>
</td>
```

Controller has -

```
 [ total3:totalValue3,total4:totalValue4]
```

how to show the appropriate value of total in template code -

```
<table >
    <tr ><td class="InputText" nowrap><b>   MessageQ Status,/td>

<tr> <td class="NoLight" nowrap>Total MessageQ : ${total+params}***/* IT SHOWS "total4" NOT THE VALUE.*/***
</td></tr>
<tr height=30></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo must change:

```
 <g:render template="gdxqStatusTemplate" model="[param:3]" />
```

By

```
 <g:render template="gdxqStatusTemplate" bean="${total3}" />
```

And in your template replace:

```
 <td class="NoLight" nowrap>Total MessageQ : ${total+params}</td>
```

By:

```
 <td class="NoLight" nowrap>Total MessageQ : ${it}</td>
```

For documentation check: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/render.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that you can use arrays or objects here? like

```
model: [total: [null, null, totalValue3, totalValue4]]
```

and use as

```
<td class="NoLight" nowrap>Total MessageQ : ${total[params]}</td>
```

Comment: did not know.thanks for suggestion,really helpful. will make change.